# Sending multiple arguments to Drupal REST Services from iPhone

Tags: iphone, drupal, rest, drupal-services

I am trying to access a Drupal service that takes more than one argument.  The method is views.get and the server I'm using is REST 6.x-2.0-beta3.  I am retrieving data from the server for 0 or 1 arguments with no trouble.  Any argument after the first, however, is simply ignored.  I have tested the view on the Drupal site, and it limits results correctly for every argument passed.

I've come to the conclusion that my problem must be the formatting, but I've tried nearly everything I can think of, not to mention a dozen suggestions I've found while Googling for an answer.  My code is below:

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

NSMutableString *httpBodyString =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"method=views.get&view_name=apps&args=1&display_id=default"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://drupalserver.com/services/rest/service_views/get.json"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[httpBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[httpBodyString release];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I have tried:

```
args=1,2
args=[1,2]
args="1,2"
args=["1","2"]
```

and several others along that vein.  Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should considering using, https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk